How to select column range based on partial column names in Pandas?
I have pandas dataframe and I am trying to select multiple columns (column range starting from Test to Bio Ref). Selection has to start from column Test to any column whose name starts with Bio. Below is the sample dataframe.
In reality it can contain:

any number of columns before Test column,
any number of columns between Test & Bio Ref like 2,3,4,5 etc.
any number of columns after Bio Ref.
Bio Ref column can contain suffix in it but Bio Ref will be there as start of column name always.

df_chunk = pd.DataFrame({
    'Waste':[None,None],
    'Test':['something', 'something'],
    '2':[None,None],
    '3':[None,None],
    'Bio Ref':['2-50','15-100'],
    'None':[None,None]})

df_chunk

   Waste         Test      2       3  Bio Ref  None
0   None    something   None    None     2-50  None
1   None    something   None    None   15-100  None

I have tried below codes that work:
df_chunk.columns.str.startswith('Bio')

df_chunk[df_chunk.columns[pd.Series(df_chunk.columns).str.startswith('Bio')==1]]

Issue: But when I try to use them for multiple column Selection then it doesn't work:
df_chunk.loc[:, 'Test':df_chunk.columns.str.startswith('Bio')]


You can creates masks for boolean indexing:
m1 = np.maximum.accumulate(df_chunk.columns=='Test')
# array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
m2 = np.maximum.accumulate(df_chunk.columns.str.startswith('Bio')[::-1])[::-1]
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False])

# m1 & m2
# array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False])

out = df_chunk.loc[:, (m1&m2)]

Or identify the correct names to build a slice:
start = 'Test'
end = next(iter(df_chunk.columns[df_chunk.columns.str.startswith('Bio')]), None)

out = df_chunk.loc[:, slice(start, end)]

Output:
        Test     2     3 Bio Ref
0  something  None  None    2-50
1  something  None  None  15-100


I would prefer second option as I won't need to import another library in that case. Thanks alot for helping me out :). Will accept the answer as soon as it let me due to time restriction.

end doesn't need to be that fancy, so you can just use df_chunk.columns[df_chunk.columns.str.startswith('Bio')][0]. Based on the question, there will always be a Bio... column; if not, then we can consider it an error instead of proceeding with None.

@wjandrea that's true, but I preferred to provide a generic solution. If there is no matching column the slice will still be valid.

Why slice(start, end) instead of the syntactical version, start:end?

Use re.match from the standard library re like so:
import re
import pandas as pd
idxs = [i for i, el in enumerate(df_chunk.columns)
        if el == 'Test' or re.match(r'^Bio', el)]
df_subset = df_chunk.iloc[:, idxs[0] : (idxs[1]+1) ]

Output:
        Test     2     3 Bio Ref
0  something  None  None    2-50
1  something  None  None  15-100

Thanks to wjandrea for the suggestion to use iloc.
See also:
pandas loc vs. iloc vs. at vs. iat?

Why use [df_chunk.columns[...]] instead of .iloc[:, ...]?

Or on the other hand, why bother with positional indexing when you could just do df_chunk.loc[:, 'Test':next(col for col in df_chunk.columns if re.match(r'^Bio', col))]?

@wjandrea Thank you for the iloc suggestion. Updated the answer.
